# Laravel 4 - Send data controller to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

**Overview:**

I have this method `getDailyTimeRecordEntry()`

```
public function getDailyTimeRecordEntry($record_id = false) {

    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    $dtr =  DailyTimeRecord::where('id', '=', $record_id)
            ->where('user_id', '=', $user_id);

    if ($dtr->count() > 0) { 
        $dtr = $dtr->first();
    } else if ($dtr->count() == 0 && $record_id != false) {

        // If other user accessing someone's record id, will redirect
        return  Redirect::route('dashboard-shinra')
                ->with('failure', 'The hell are you accessing someone\'s record?');
    }

    // if the dtr->count() is 0 or has a value it still send the data to view
    return  View::make('dashboard.shinra.dtr_entry')
            ->with('dtr', $dtr);
}
```

So we know that whether the url has a parameter of record id or blank, it still send the `dtr` value that I'm passing to view

Without parameter:
`www.mydomain.com/dashboard/shinra/daily-time-record-entry`

With parameter:
`www.mydomain.com/dashboard/shinra/daily-time-record-entry/2`

So on the view `dashboard.shinra.dtr_entry`

I have this certain line of code that has a `dtr` variable in it.

```
<input type="text" name="date" value="{{ ($dtr->date) ? $dtr->date : '' }}">
```

So, if we access

`www.mydomain.com/dashboard/shinra/daily-time-record-entry/1`

All the records will be output in the text fields like the input above. Because the parameter `1` has a record in database.

So if I access

`www.mydomain.com/dashboard/shinra/daily-time-record-entry`

Without the parameter, I'm encountering the error

[image]

I know that it's because of this one

```
{{ ($dtr->date) ? $dtr->date : '' }}
```

But, are there any fix for this?

I even tried

```
{{ (isset($dtr->date)) ? $dtr->date : '' }}
```

And still doesn't work.

Comment: are you getting any results back from database if no parameter is set  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that edge case, when count is 0 and you never execute the query.

So first I would suggest naming variables appropriately:

```
$query =  DailyTimeRecord::where('id', '=', $record_id)
        ->where('user_id', '=', $user_id);
...

$dtr = $query->first(); // or whatever
...
return View::make()->with('dtr', $dtr);
```

Then you would already know, that `$dtr` is unset, so it's pretty easy to debug.

Now, your code executes queries, that are not necessary:

```
// 1st query
if ($dtr->count() > 0) { 
// 2nd query if passed
    $dtr = $dtr->first();

// 2nd query if didn't pass
} else if ($dtr->count() == 0 && $record_id != false) {
```

While you could do it as simply as this:

```
$dtr = DailyTimeRecord::where('id', '=', $record_id)
        ->where('user_id', '=', $user_id)
        ->first();

if ( ! count($dtr))
{
  return ... // ERROR
}

return ... // correct row returned
```

Answer (score 1):

In your method `getDailyTimeRecordEntry()`, you should also handle the case `($dtr->count() == 0 && $record_id == false)` for when the `$record_id` is `false`. Otherwise you can have a situation where you don't `get()` or `first()` the `$dtr` query.

So you should have:

```
public function getDailyTimeRecordEntry($record_id = false) {

    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    $dtr =  DailyTimeRecord::where('id', '=', $record_id)
            ->where('user_id', '=', $user_id);

    if ($dtr->count() > 0) { 
        $dtr = $dtr->first();
    } else if ($dtr->count() == 0 && $record_id != false) {

        // If other user accessing someone's record id, will redirect
        return  Redirect::route('dashboard-shinra')
                ->with('failure', 'The hell are you accessing someone\'s record?');
    } else {
        // return something or make sure you do $dtr = $dtr->first() here
        $dtr = $dtr->first();
    }

    // if the dtr->count() is 0 or has a value it still send the data to view
    return  View::make('dashboard.shinra.dtr_entry')
            ->with('dtr', $dtr);
}
```

Also, you can use simpler syntax for the ternary operator in Blade. Instead of writing

```
{{ (isset($dtr->date)) ? $dtr->date : '' }}
```

you can write

```
{{ $dtr->date or '' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like if you have no parameters set the id would be 0. That would imply you're getting an empty collection in your $dtr and passing that empty collection to the view. Than you're trying to access attribute of what you're thinking is model but in reality its a collection.

This might or not be the case based on what your db is returning when no parameter is passed to the controllers action.